# Linux doesn't see Windows Boot Manager while installing

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, boot, installation

On the other day I was installing Linux on my new laptop, which I just have obtained. It didn't have any system preinstalled so I installed Windows 10. After that I realized that I want to do some job on Linux and decided to install Ubuntu for dualbooting them.
Everything went as usual until it asked me where do I want to install Linux. Wonder what happened? It didn't suggest me to install Linux alongside with Windows Boot Manager. The only options I've got were "Erase disk" and "Something else".

Windows is working fine and boots everytime.

`os-prober` says this:

```
grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb2. Check your device.map.
```

It may be caused by Legacy Mode, which is currently on. I've got a UEFI.

P.S. I did a ton of researching (2 months) and can't find something to work. Please, help...

Comment: Most likely all your disk space is assigned to Windows - have you freed up some space, that is not assigned to a windows drive?

Comment: I have only one drive in my laptop,  a 500GB SSD. I freed up 100GB but it didn't change whatever

Comment: What do you mean by "freed up" - if it is 100GB free on Windows C:, then it is still assigned to Windows. The free space must show as "unassigned" in Windows disk anager

Comment: First.. what @Eugen_Rieck said.. Second.. where does "Something else" take you?  I have installed as you are doing countless times.  I have to do manual partitioning using the parted built into the installer.. I have never had it actually mention windows.. after it drops down GRUB2.. it seems to always work where windows is one of the entries on my grub menu which magically calls windows' bcd boot crap.

Comment: It is goddamn unallocated space. I literally chopped 100GB from my disk and now there is 100GB of unallocated space. @EugenRieck

Comment: Maybe it is a Windows "Dynamic Disk" ? This does not really release the "unallocated space", but keeps it reserved for Windows LVM. If it is a single disk, you can easily convert it to a "base disk" (Sorry if the wording is wrong, I only have access to german WIndows)